# Finding exact string match inside of a larger string using Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, indexof

I am trying to find a good solution for this problem. I am currently using indexOf to compare 2 strings, but the problem is that it is returning matching words when I need it to return exact matches. The string "topics" contains the following. "Computer Eyewear, Eyewear, Blue Light, Cataracts. "See Example below. The variable selection will return one of the matching phrases in the string as it loops through the page.

```
var topics = "Computer Eyewear, Eyewear, Blue Light, Cataracts";

if ($('.post_wrapper').length > 0) { 

        $('.post_wrapper').find('.post_item').each(function() {

            var selection = $(this).find('h2').html();

            if (topics.indexOf(selection) >= 0) {

            //do stuff here

            }

     });

});
```

The problem is that when I am trying to match with "Computer Eyewear" it also matches with "Eyewear". I need a method that will match with each of these more specifically.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the topics variable as a string, define it as array:

```
var topics = ["Computer Eyewear", "Eyewear", "Blue Light", "Cataracts"];
```

As it happens, arrays also have an `indexOf` method, which will work as expected in your case.

There is however a more efficient way to do it. For that you would create these strings as property names:

```
var topics = {
    "Computer Eyewear": 1,
    "Eyewear": 1,
    "Blue Light": 1,
    "Cataracts": 1
};
```

And with this setup the `if` condition has to change to:

```
if (selection in topics) {
```

The gain compared to the first method of working will only be relevant if you have many, many topics to verify.

Comment: I was able to split my string into an array, and accomplish what I was trying to do. Thank you for the Array idea!